Proofs of the loop-suspension adjunction in infinity-categories
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Map}{Map}$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Fun}{Fun}$$\DeclareMathOperator{\const}{const}$$\DeclareMathOperator{\colim}{colim}$$\DeclareMathOperator{\lim}{lim}$In Elements of $\infty$-Category Theory by Riehl-Verity a proof of the $\Omega-\Sigma$ adjunction is given for pointed $\infty$-categories.
If we assume that $\mathcal{C}$ admits all pullbacks and pushouts, then the proof is relatively simple: the $\Omega-\Sigma$ adjunction can be obtained as an appropriate restriction of the adjunctions
$$\mathcal{C}^{\Lambda^2_2} \overset{\text{res}}{\underset{\text{ran}}{\leftrightarrows}}
\mathcal{C}^{\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1} \overset{\text{lan}}{\underset{\text{res}}{\leftrightarrows}} \mathcal{C}^{\Lambda^2_2}
$$
where the upper functors are the left adjoints.
In Riehl-Verity a proof is also given without the assumption that $\mathcal{C}$ admits arbitrary pushouts and pullbacks, see Proposition 4.4.4 there.
The proofs in Riehl-Verity make use of the fact that adjunctions of $\infty$-categories can be specified at the level of $2$-categories, which is discussed in the same book. This doesn't seem "essential" (at least with the arbitraty pushout/pullback assumption): the adjunctions above also follow from Proposition 4.3.2.17 in HTT, where the $2$-categorical characterization of adjunctions is not used.
Since the $\Omega-\Sigma$ adjunction is a nice and basic result, I thought it would be instructive to know some different proofs (if they exist).
Besides being interested in any proof, I have two proof ideas in mind which I wonder if they can be made complete. To explain these, note that the forgetful functor from the full subcategory of $\Fun(\Lambda^2_0, \mathcal{C})$ spanned by objects of the form $\ast \xleftarrow{} X \xrightarrow{} \ast$ down to $\mathcal{C}$ is a trivial Kan fibration (follows from the fact that the zero object $\ast$ is initial) and hence admits a section $\iota$. Hence we can define $\Sigma := \colim_{\Lambda^2_0} \circ \iota$ and similarly define $\Omega:= \lim_{\Lambda^2_2} \circ \iota'$, where $\iota'$ is defined similarly, sending $Y$ to $\ast \xrightarrow{} Y \xleftarrow{} \ast$.
Then the first idea is to show that there are equivalences of functors
\begin{align}
\Map_{\mathcal{C}}(\Sigma -, -)  
& \cong  \Map_{\Fun(\Lambda^2_0, \mathcal{C})}(\iota(-), \const(-)) \\
& \cong  \Map_{\Fun(\Lambda^2_2, \mathcal{C})}(\const(-), \iota'(-) ) \\
& \cong \Map_{\mathcal{C}}(-, \Omega -)
\end{align}
which suffices by 8.3.4.9 on Kerodon for example.
The first equivalence follows from the fact that colimit functors are left adjoint to constant diagrams, see Propositions 5.1.5 and 5.1.24 in Land's book on $\infty$-categories (2021 version). The last equivalence is dual, so the hole in this idea is second equivalence.
The second idea is to observe that $\Sigma$ preserves colimits and to then use an adjoint functor theorem to define $\Omega$ as its right adjoint. But then the hole in the proof would be to show that this $\Omega$ is equivalent to the one given above.
I guess I do not really care whether proofs require $\mathcal{C}$ to have abitrary pullbacks and pushouts or not (in fact this assumption is necessary for how I defined $\Sigma$ and $\Omega$). I am just hoping to maybe learn some new ideas - I would be happy to accept an answer which completes one of the ideas above, or which gives entirely different proof. Also I would be happy to hear about any flaws in my question. Thanks in advance!
